# What is the apt (apt-get) --option used for?

Tags: apt

Could a kind soul tell me about the `apt --option`?

1. What does it do?
2. How is it used?
3. What options are set up via this flag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `man apt`:

```
   -o, --option
       Set a Configuration Option; This will set an arbitrary configuration option.
       The syntax is -o Foo::Bar=bar.  -o and --option can be used multiple times
       to set different options.
```

For example,
if you are behind a proxy,
and want to test with different proxy setting values,
you could do this:

```
apt-get update -o Acquire::http::Proxy "http://yourproxyaddress:proxyport"
```

When you are not sure of the correct setting value, testing different values using the `-o` option can be more practical than editing a config file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`, saving and re-running the command. The `-o` option let's you skip the file editing part, and play with different values more directly.

More generally, the purpose of this option is to temporarily override any configuration value.
As @steeldriver pointed out in a comment,
the available options and option syntax are documented in the `apt.conf` manual page (`man apt.conf`).

Comment: As I realized, this is the option for apt setup, not for installed software?

Comment: Yes, it's for apt itself, not for packages it installs.

Comment: FYI the available options and option syntax are documented in the apt.conf manual page `man apt.conf`